# How to use Hazelcast with restful?

Tags: java, .net, rest, caching, hazelcast

I want to use Hazelcast in my Java application, but I also have .net applications which need to get/set data to/from the Hazelcast cache. I thought to use the "rest" approach. I have 2 questions:

1) How can I post and get a complex type? If I have a `Person` object with fields `name` (String), `age` (Integer), `birthDate` (Date), and `sex` (Enum), how should I post this info and how should I parse person info?

2) I have a cached `IMap<String, String>`. After I post data "three" with key "3" from a Poster plugin, on the Java side `map.get("3")` returns something like:

```
RestValue{contentType='text/plain;charset=utf-8', value="three"}"
```

I expect this code to return just "three" without any cast operation.

I will be pleased if you give information about this issues.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you solved your issue? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a couple of different types of issues here with your current setup.

1) I don't have a good answer for this because I don't actually know much about rest clients in `.net`. You also may also get better results if you change your architecture as mentioned below.

2) It looks like the problem you have here is that you're just storing the raw request object(`RestValue`) in the `IMap` rather than storing the content of that object. Usually requests to a rest api contain more information than just the value sent to your server so you'll have to extract the value from the `RestValue` in your rest api. Hazelcast `RestValue` has a method called `getValue()`, so you should just be able to call `getValue()` which returns a `byte[]`. You should then just convert that `byte[]` to a `String` (or whatever datatype you prefer to store, maybe `int` in this case) and store the result in your `IMap` instead of just storing the entire `RestValue` object.

As far as having .net + java architecture, it may be best to run a Hazelcast-server node in whichever language you prefer and then have a .net hazelcast-client node and a java hazelcast-client node that are all connected to the same cluster. This way you can have all of your .net code run on your .net client completely separattd from your java infrastructure and communicate between the separate languages using hazelcast.